# E: Unable to locate package azure-functions-core-tools-4

Tags: debian, apt, docker

Running a docker container, trying to install `azure-functions-core-tools-4`. I can search for the package in the configured repo, but it fails to find the package when I try to install it. I have already run `apt update` several times, so that's not it.

```
root@eddf41a4eea9:/app# apt install azure-functions-core-tools-4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package azure-functions-core-tools-4
root@eddf41a4eea9:/app# apt search azure-functions-core-tools
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
azure-functions-core-tools-3/bullseye 3.0.3904-1 amd64
  Azure Function Core Tools v3

azure-functions-core-tools-4/bullseye 4.0.3971-1 amd64
  Azure Function Core Tools v3
```

Some more information

```
root@eddf41a4eea9:/app# cat /etc/*release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
```

Contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list`

```
root@eddf41a4eea9:/app# cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list
deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/11/prod bullseye main
```

Comment: Running `grep -Ei ^package.+azure /var/lib/apt/lists/*` will show you what is available for azure and nothing resembles what you are looking for. Closest is `azure-cli`

Comment: I ended up downloading the `.deb` straight from the repo and trying to do a local install. That failed as well. I'm almost certain it's because my laptop (and thus the container) have the wrong architecture. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out the issue. My docker container is running on my macbook with an M1 cpu and ARM architecture.

```
root@eddf41a4eea9:/tmp# lscpu
Architecture:                    aarch64
```

I think what I will end up doing is rebuilding the container with cross architecture support.

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/multi-arch/